# Request.body is empty object after put request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch

I make put request, but my request.body is empty object

main.js

```
company = await fetch(`http://localhost:8080/companies/${company.id}`, {
         method: "PUT",
         body: JSON.stringify({ name: "my company" }), 
         headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'} })
         .then(res => res.json()).then(data => data);
```

company.route.js

```
this.__router.put('/:id', (req, res) => {
      const { body, params: { id } } = req;
      console.log(body);

      companyController.updateOne(id, body);
      res.status(200).end();
    });
```

company.controller.js

```
updateOne(id, {name}) {
    const company = this.findOne(id);

    company.name = name || company.name;
    return company;
  }
```

app.js

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/*' , function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded())

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: There is no `fetch` method provided by Node, please include the statements that import `fetch` so it is clear where the definition of it comes from.

Comment: @amn no, fetch works, my post, get, and delete requests works.

Comment: Where is `fetch` defined? Without knowing what `fetch` does, how can you expect anyone to help you debug this?

Comment: Try with the postman, if it works then your code has some issues.

Comment: @KrinaSoni In postman I have error Cannot set property &#39;name&#39; of undefined

Comment: you can always add body in PUT request. Check have you selected PUT from dropdown?

Comment: @KrinaSoni Yes, then I choosed body->row and type {
 "name": "my company"
} then clicked send button